# Generate a PDF from HTML with tags for accessibility

Tags: html, pdf, accessibility, jspdf, jaws-screen-reader

I want to generate a PDF from HTML that has tags for accessibility embedded in it.  In other words I want to convert HTML to PDF so that it is JAWS-friendly.  The standard options out there for generating PDFs from HTML do not embed accessibility tags in the exported PDF.  For example, there are various plug-ins for jsPDF and none of them have the ability to add the appropriate accessibility tags.  Any one have experience with this?

Comment: Glass duo, Where you able to figure out more on this process?

Answer (score 6):

Just mentioning that I found an open-source 508 / WCAG 2.0 / PDF-EU compliant PDF generation library that is worth a look.

I haven't evaluated it yet (will later today), but the project has 1000 stars on github and 200 forks:

- https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf

Here's their glorious and concise write-up on compliance:

- https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf/wiki/PDF-Accessibility-(PDF-UA,-WCAG,-Section-508)-Support

Comment: Follow-up: It's a great choice. My company (in the healthcare industry in 49 states) adopted it as a de-facto PDF generation library.

Comment: A big plus also is that you can use all your HTML and CSS skills to make beautiful looking PDFs without using puppeteer (and the memory overhead that needs).

Comment: Also the community has a very fast response time. I needed a a feature completed, and it was handled in a week.

Comment: Here's their sample project that is rendering an html and AngularJS document:
- https://github.com/danfickle/pretty-resume

Comment: FYI, I'm not affiliated with this project, I'm just a fan.

Answer (score 2):

That's extremely sad, but there are very few libraries able to generate accessible PDFs.
To my knowledge, none of the free and/or very popular ones are able to do it. None out there in JavaScript or PHP at least.

The only one I know of is [iText](https://itextpdf.com/). It's Java, and quite expensive if you need to have a commercial license.

By the way, it's important to note that, when you open a PDF directly in your browser, given that they often use these same JavaScript libraries to render PDFs back into HTML, even if your PDF has accessibility tags, they aren't rendered back with accessibility in the browser.
The PDF has to be opened into a real PDF reader like Adobe Reader in order for the user to read the PDF accessibly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This sounds like a development opportunity to me. If only I had the time to dedicate to something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Apache PDFbox is a free alternative to iText https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/documentinterchange/taggedpdf/package-summary.html